# Creating SQL Server Login: password problem

Tags: sql-server

We have a SqlServer database that we run using Windows Authorization. I want to set up a server login for a particular user who is remoting in. In the management tool, I enter the user name, password, and confirm the password. Then save. The user is unable to log in.

When I re-open the login, the password appears to have been changed. It's a different number of characters. Since they are obscured, I can not see what they are.

It's not a problem with the management tool. Same result with two different SQL Managers.

What's going on?

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, the password is hidden and the number of 'dots' does not represent the number of characters from the original password.

secondly, when the user remoting in has to enter their username/password, this suggests that you are NOT using the windows authentication, but *Sql Server Authentication*. This means you'll need to create Sql server users and set the server to allow MIXED authentication (both Windows auth and sql server auth).

If u need help with

1. creating a test sql server user account
2. setting the sql server to allow mixed authentication

please just ask away in the comments.

#### Edit

This information applies to all version of sql server, as far as i believe

Comment: Thanks for the hint about the number of dots. That led me astray.

It pays to read error messages carefully. The login was being rejected because it did not have rights on the default database, not because the login/pw was bad. 

Thanks for the help.

Comment: ahh!!! i new i was missing something from the list above. nice work :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows Authenticate and the remote user is being prompted for login information, they may not be authenticated to your domain/server when they connect.  Make sure they enter the fully qualified username along with their password.  (e.g. MYDOMAIN\userx or userx@MYDOMAIN.local..)

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the password the remote user is entering matches the one that was created, then two things are possible: (1) when creating the login the DBA selected to *Enforce password expiration* and/or (2) selected *User must change password at next login*.

Resolution = Drop and recreate the login w/o selecting either option above.

The other issue may be that the login does not have rights associated with the default database it's been assigned.  Check to see if there is a user in that database that maps to the login in question.

Resolution = map a user in the db back to the server login.